# Change font color for TheBoooking plugin

Tags: wordpress

I would to change the font colors the plugin. My website's background is black thus some words cant be seen. I would like to change the fonts color to white. I would appreciate if you could guide me on this matter. Thank you

I tried using the settings in WordPress > customize > TheBooking